# Wifi stops working after a while unless I renew DHCP (MB Pro Retina, Late 2013)

Tags: macos, internet, dhcp, macbook-pro, wifi-configuration

It started a while back. I think it happened when I updated to Yosemite, it happened when I updated to El Capitan. Wifi works fine for less than half an hour, then it stops working. It doesn't get disconnected, it just stops working. When I turn wifi on and off it starts working again, for a while.

Not sure if it helps but when I renew DHCP it starts working again (having trouble with the ip?). I'm sure it's not hardware-related because it works fine when I'm using other networks It's only with my home network that I have this problem. I don't anything is wrong with my network either because all my other devices (PC/cell phone/tablet) work fine. I've tried all the suggestions, last one I remember is reseting my PRAM. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Change the DHCP lease time in your router, simplest potential fix.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't have that option. Wouldn't all my devices have this problem if it was related to my modem?

Comment: I'm interested to hear more details.  Perhaps we have the same symptoms: Clicking Renew DHCP has the advantage over bouncing AirPort altogether because it temporarily resolves it without interrupting other connections (like active SSH in terminal).
I tend to associate the "wifi freezing" with websites with many images (google image results) as well as some streaming services but not others.  It's as if I "only have so many pipes," and when one gets clogged, everything stops.
Hardwired ethernet does not suffer this effect.

Comment: I have the same issue at home. My 2017 MBpro loses interenet every 10 minutes and I have to renew DHCP lease to get it back.  My wifes older MB has the exact same issue. But our lenovo and HP laptops dont have this issue, nor do our ipads, iphones and android phones. - seems to be a MacOS only problem.  It could be an incompatibility issue with Macs and the router.  Its pretty difficult to work.

Comment: I have a similar issue with both my previous MacBook Pro and my current one.  Both were the only devices that had this issue on my home wifi.  Very odd.  There must be a bug/setting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

when that happened are you can go to access point web page?

i see you writed : "It's only with my home network that I have this problem"
and in other place write: "all my other devices (PC/cell phone/tablet) work fine"
if your other device not any problem with your home network then maybe your pc have antivirus and i think u must deactive it and see what happened.

but if your home network not worked for all your device then i think your problem for "Connection Setting" in your access point, for that you must change that setting to "always on".

i wish this help to you.

Comment: I'm on wifi so no, I thought it only works if you're using ethernet cable. Yes my PC has an anti-virus but it's my Macbook Pro that is having difficulty mainting a stable connection, not my PC. You're right, my other devices don't have this problem. I'm not sure what you by the last sentence, sorry.